# How to invoke a stored procedure asynchronously using PanacheRepository and Hibernate Reactive in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, quarkus-panache, hibernate-reactive, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

How to invoke a stored procedure asynchronously and accept the returned result using PanacheRepository (not active record pattern) in an application bootstrapped with Quarkus 3.5.0 and Reactive Hibernate with Panache?

I tried injecting the EntityManager within my repository and performed the synchronous operation within a Uni emitter hoping it would offload it to a worker thread as follows

```
Uni.createFrom().emitter(emitter -> {
  entityManager.createNativeQuery("call procName(1, 2)", Integer.class).executeUpdate();
});
```

But vert.x complains of a blocking IO and errors out with

```
> io.quarkus.runtime.BlockingOperationNotAllowedException: You have
> attempted to perform a blocking operation on a IO thread. This is not
> allowed, as blocking the IO thread will cause major performance issues
> with your application. If you want to perform blocking EntityManager
> operations make sure you are doing it from a worker thread.
>         at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.checkBlocking(TransactionScopedSession.java:116)
>         at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.createNativeQuery(TransactionScopedSession.java:434)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.createNativeQuery(SessionLazyDelegator.java:686)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.createNativeQuery(SessionLazyDelegator.java:66)
>         at org.hibernate.Session_3a974b6a18ac399f675913d732c105426414d370_Synthetic_ClientProxy.createNativeQuery(Unknown
> Source)
```

There are no async methods on the Query object.
What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like Panache has an API to make the call. Used EntityManagerFactory instead

```
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny;

@Inject
EntityManagerFactory emf;

public Uni<Integer> myFunc() {
  Mutiny.SessionFactory factory = emf.unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
  return factory.withSession(session -> { session.createNativeQuery(storedProcedureCall).getSingleResultOrNull()
}
```

Comment: However, it always expects a return value and cannot handle a stored proc that doesnt return anything with `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because the return value of "io.vertx.sqlclient.RowSet.columnsNames()" is null`

Comment: This seems a bug, could you create an issue here, please: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues ?

Comment: If the query doesn't return values, you should use `.executeUpdate()` and not `.getSingleResultOrNull()`. We will check if it's possible to improve the error message

Answer (score 0):

`getSingleResultOrNull` only works for queries returning a result, you should use `executeUpdate`.

This should work:

```java
import org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny;

@Inject
Mutiny.SessionFactory factory;

public Uni<Integer> myFunc() {
    return factory.withTransaction(session -> session
                       .createNativeQuery( storedProcedureCall )
                       .executeUpdate()
    );
}
```

Note that you can inject the `Mutiny.SessionFactory` directly, and you need to make sure that there's a transaction because this is an update.

The error message is not user friendly though, we will try to come up with something better.

Comment: I assume you mean `createMutationQuery()`.executeUpdate()

Comment: `createMutationQuery` is for HQL queries, `createNativeQuery` is for SQL queries. The question uses native queries, so I've used the same.

Comment: https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/2.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/reactive/mutiny/Mutiny.MutationQuery.html#executeUpdate()

https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/2.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/reactive/mutiny/Mutiny.SelectionQuery.html#getResultList()

`createNativeQuery` returns a SelectionQuery and I don't see `executeUpdate()` on the interface. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes. [createNativeQuery](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/2.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/reactive/mutiny/Mutiny.Session.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)) returns a [Mutiny.Query](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/2.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/reactive/mutiny/Mutiny.Query.html). `Mutiny.Query` extends `Mutiny.MutationQuery`. `Mutiny.MutationQuery` has [executeUpdate](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/2.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/reactive/mutiny/Mutiny.MutationQuery.html#executeUpdate())